# Windows 10 touch keyboard doesn't dock or 'maximize' at the bottom of the screen

Tags: windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

I tried to find this answer by myself for 3 hours, but I failed.  I need some help.

While I was using Windows 8 touch keyboard, I can click the maximize button from the touch keyboard, which makes the keyboard dock at the bottom of the screen (ie not hover).  In this case, I can see the whole maximized program window from top to bottom (Internet Explorer, Notepad, Chrome, etc) above the touch keyboard.

However, the Windows 10 touch keyboard doesn't dock at the bottom.  It looks like it is located at the bottom of the screen but actually it is located **over** the programs.  I can't see the bottom contents because it is covered by touch keyboard.

Is there any option I can change that will solve this? Is this intended behaviour or a bug? Do I need to find a different touch or virtual keyboard?

If it is not working, I need to go back to windows 8. Please help me!

***Updated** at 08/11/2015

I have tried with tablet mode because someone told me it would work.
I have tried to use MS Edge with tablet mode and **surprisingly** it works.
I have tried to use iExplorer (executing from Edge) with tablet mode and it doesn't work.
I have tried to use Calendar (from windows 10) with tablet mode and it doesn't work.
I have tried to use file explorer with tablet mode and it doesn't work.
I have tried to use notepad (simple notepad from window) with tablet mode and it doesn't work.
Don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Can nobody help me?

Comment: I found a program called [TouchZoomDesktop](http://www.lovesummertrue.com/touchzoomdesktop/en-us/index.html) that allow you to swipe the screen when you dock touch keyboard. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is also a big issue for me since our software relies heavily on the onscreen keyboard. Is there any official Microsoft page where this functionality can be requested? I only found this same post in the  [Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop/windows-10-touch-keyboard-doesnt-dock/3c253400-568f-4e89-a253-0d7a747b5b63) but with no official feedback. I can't believe more people experience problems with this...

Answer (score 6):

This feature is broken in Windows 10 since early preview, and makes the tablet experience considerably worse than on Windows 8.1

**Workaround exists:** The only situation where the docked keyboard still works is when the window is not maximized. You can windows+left and then resize the window full screen to get a maximized-like experience while still retaining dock functionality.

Comment: It starts to behave really funny if you fake a maximized window by sizing a normal window _exactly_ as large as the desktop working area (e.g. the screen without the taskbar). It stops shrinking the window then too, even though it's not maximized. I guess there's some dumb code comparing the window size. And I wonder if it can be removed with a hack...

Answer (score 3):

I've just discovered an external application [Tabtip On-Demand](http://chessware.ch/tabtipod/), which makes Windows 10 touch keyboard working better.

I'm currently testing it and after a while it looks like it works as advertised. However it is **payed** software, so You have to consider if You want to pay for it.

I'm in no way related to creators of this software, found it in [similar thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/3zbj8k/onscreen_keyboard_no_longer_resizes_windows/).

Answer (score 3):

Rightclick on taskbar->Show touch keyboard button and you will see the dockable version of Windows 10 keyboard next to the clock/date/language area

Comment: Who knew Microsoft managed to squeeze in *two different on-screen keyboards*?! While they cannot run at the same time, the elegant compact docked version can only be triggered via the icon on the status bar. Thank you for this!

Comment: can it dock?  my windows still appear behind the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

there ia a crappy workaround, use split screen mode! while having two windowsbside by side in tablet mode resizing works as expected...

Comment: This just repeats the existing answer.